# My button wont work using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a chrome extension. and my chrome extension has a table with buttons on it. But unfortunately the my buttons won't work and there's no errors in the console..

**My question is why my button id in my address.js `"copy"` wont triggered an alert**

**This is my home.html in my chrome extension**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src= "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src = "address.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p><br/><br/></p>
    <div class = "container">
            <table id="example" class = "table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead> 
                    <tr>
                  <th>Video Name</th>
                  <th>File Name</th>
                  <th>Copy</th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>

            </table>
    </div>



  </body>
</html>
```

**And this is my address.js**

```
$.getJSON("http://mlearningessentials.com/vid.php", function(data){

  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val){
    items.push("<tr>");
    items.push("<td  id=''"+key+"''>"+val.video_name+"</td>");
        items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.file_name+"</td>");
          items.push("<td>"+'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="copy">Copy</button>'+"</td>");



        items.push("</tr>");
 });

  $("<tbody/>", {html: items.join("")}).appendTo("table");

});


 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#copy").click(function(){
      alert('copied');


    });
  })
```

Comment: Learn  [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) use code `$(document).on("click","#copy",function(){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger event `dynamically`

```
$(document).on("click","#copy",function(){
  alert('copied');
});
```

Read more about [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to understand how it works.

Comment: Thank you sir its working now. and I will read that docu :)

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically added elements you have bind the click a bit differently(**Event delegation**). Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#copy", function() {
  alert('copied');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By dynamic DOM try this

```
$(document).on("click", "#copy", function() {
  alert('copy');

});
```